# Why is my rigid body object floating as if there is no gravity?

Tags: animation, physics, rigid-body-simulation, parent

I have two issues on my current file that I cant seem to solve (see link below)?

1) why is the hat being thrown appearing like it is floating and not affected by gravity towards the end of the animation, even though I have applied rigid body active to it?

2) How can I make the hat spin around with the robot body at the start of the animation, even though it is already parented to robot hand with "Cild Of".

Any help here is appreciated.[image]

Here is the Blend file link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vaxriy8lfo1palg/robotHat2-animated_ridgid%20body-copy%20float%20hat.blend?dl=0
[image]

Comment: read this https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344/where-to-upload-blend-files-non-expiring-links and [edit] your question with the correct .blend file link

Comment: Yes, sorry I put the wrong link in the original post, but I have just eddied it with correct link.

Comment: Please don't use dropbox links, upload your file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Is it free to use? I thought you needed a subscription.

Comment: Free to use, just read the T&Cs and tick the boxes

Comment: Done! I have added tle blend-exchange link in original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved this problem. Here is the link to the successful project file output:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wmTCE0c4SrI

The solution:
1st problem:  the point of origin in the post was too low and needed to be moved up. This required to rework all the animations from scratch.

2nd problem: the gravity settings needed to be adjusted and animated along the time line to get a more realistic result. And the friction and damping settings needed tweaking, as well as animating them with key frames. And voila.